# Can I use Perf4J across processes?

Tags: java, distributed, perf4j

I'm integrating Perf4J in a distributed application, where a task can be
prepared on one server and executed on another. We'd really like to be able to
track the performance of these tasks including the inter-process transport
component, but the standard Perf4J implementation doesn't seem to work like
that.

It does look like you can serialize a StopWatch object, but it seems like it
would be more efficient to just pass a start time value in the work packet and
then initialize the StopWatch with that start time on the receiving end (the
servers' clocks are synchronized using NTP). I do see a StopWatch constructor
that takes a start time and an elapsed time, but the JavaDoc says it "should
normally not be called by third party code."

Is there a good way to track the performance of a task that begins in one process and
completes on another, using Perf4J or another tool?

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problematic. Did you find the way to go ?

Comment: Not really. I did get one suggestion to use separate stopwatches on the different nodes and log a job ID in the tag, then aggregate the numbers from the common job IDs out of the log files and generate a report from that. But that seemed to be more trouble than it was worth in my case.